# Controlling importing optional/extra libraries in python

Tags: python, import, module

Setuptools allows you to define extra dependencies. How can you optionally import these?

As an example, consider a db wrapper that may provide some functionality for a myriad of databases

setup.py

```
extras_require={
    'postgres': ['postgresLibrary'],
    'mysql': ['mysqlLibrary'],
    ...
},
```

class definition

```
import postgresLibrary  <--- these imports will fail if extras not installed
import mysqlLibrary     


class DB:
    def __init__(self, db_type):
        if db_type == 'postgres':
            self.conn = PostgresConnection()
        elif db_type == 'mysql':
            self.conn == MySQLConnection()
        ...
```

setup.py may allow the end user to selectively install their chosen db library, but I'm not clear on what the best way to selectively import the libraries is. I hesitate to import them within a function or constructor, but I can't think of any other way to do it, other than to require the end user to install all the libraries they may not want/need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the few cases in python where I think a singleton design pattern might be useful - as a mechanism to *selectively* keep global variables in memory. For example, instead of

```
import postgresLibrary
import mysqlLibrary
```

you'd make a class that keeps track of the modules that are currently imported, and only *tries* to import them the first time they're used. For example, file `singleton.py`:

```
class SingletonBase:
    def __init__(self):
        self._modules = {}
    def __getattr__(self, module_name):
        if not module_name in self._modules:
            self._modules[module_name] = __import__(module_name)
        return self._modules[module_name]

Singleton = SingletonBase()
```

You could then use `postgresLibrary` locally by doing something along the lines of

```
from singleton import Singleton as S
...
postgresLibrary = S.postgresLibrary.PostgresConnection()
```

Comment: I think this will work. It does still import the files inside a function/method as opposed to the start of the file. I'm not opposed to that at all, and I think this will avoid the continual import call

Comment: Yes it does import them inside a function/method, but it does so dynamically, and avoids ever loading the modules more than once (e.g. the normal issue with importing modules inside methods is that you need to re-import them every time the method is called, which wastes a lot of time).

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit of a hack, but one option would be to wrap the import in a try/except block. If the postgres library isn't available, and the user tries to initialize a db object with the db_type of postgres, you could raise an exception then for the missing import.

My original answer would not work, but I'm leaving it here so the comments make sense.

<s>**One way** to do it would be to create a class for each type of database. The main DB class wouldn't need the optional imports, and the postgres db class would need the postgres library, but not the the mysql library.</s>

```
class DB:
    def __init__(self, db_type):
        if db_type == 'postgres':
            self.db = PostgresDB()
        elif db_type == 'mysql':
            self.db == MySQLDB()
        ...
   def get_connection(self):
        return self.db.conn
```

```
import postgresLibrary
class PostgresDB:
    def __init__(self):
    self.conn = PostgresConnection
```

Comment: You'd have to import PostgresDB from the other file, and in doing so, you'll trigger the import in the new file, right? Or have I missed something? The try/except would work, I just wasn't sure if that was the best way to do it.

Comment: the other file would only be called if a Postgres type was selected.

At the end of the day, if someone is trying to use your library, they are going to have to have either the postgres library you are using or the mysql library you are using installed.

Comment: true, but you can't have PostgresDB() in there unless its imported right? So once you import it from the other file (say `from postgresdb import PostgresDB`) its going to trigger the import of the postgresLibrary. My point is I think you're missing the imports from the original file (gotta import the classes before you can use them) and once you import them, the offending imports are triggered.

Comment: yes, you are correct. wasn't thinking all the way through on that one.

Comment: I can't comment on other answers yet (not enough rep points) but Green Cloak Guy's answer of importing within the required methods seems to match what is going on with SQL Alchemy. https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/connectors/mxodbc.py